# In AppleScript, what is the easiest way to remove all punctuation from a string?

Tags: macos, applescript, text

I have an Automator Service that is comprised of a single *"Run AppleScript"* action. The Service receives selected `text` in `any application`.

The Service incorporates this selected text into a pre-determined URL format. The Service then opens the newly-assembled URL in a new tab in a web browser window.

Here is a string that the Service might receive:

> My Plant's Dead! (But, Who Cares? I Have 12 Plants.)

I want to use AppleScript to remove every and any punctuation symbol that exists in the string, including spaces. I also need the string to be converted to all lowercase characters. Numbers should not be removed from the string.

So, the desired string is:

```
myplantsdeadbutwhocaresihave12plants
```

I understand that I can accomplish the desired effect by writing an individual `text item delimiters` statement for every possible punctuation symbol and for 26 uppercase letters. I could use a [`replace_characters` sub-routine](https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-06.html) to make this method a bit neater.

Is there an easier or shorter way to accomplish this effect in AppleScript, as opposed to using dozens of `text item delimiters` blocks? Such as, one line of code that reduces a string to letters?

I know that other programming languages have a "strip punctuation" shortcut, which is why I ask.

This is, essentially, an AppleScript-specific ["Code Golf"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
set stringToConvert to "My Plant's Dead! (But, Who Cares? I Have 12 Plants.)"
set returnedString to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of stringToConvert & " | tr -dc '[:alnum:]' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'"
```

It returns: `myplantsdeadbutwhocaresihave12plants`

`tr` commands explained:

- `tr -dc '[:alnum:]'` deletes all non alphanumeric characters (including white space).
- `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` converts all upper-case characters to lower-case characters.

See the man page for [`tr`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tr.1.html).

Comment: Thanks for bringing the numbers point to my attention; I had completely forgotten about this.

Comment: @rubik's sphere, Auto-correct changed `alnum` to  `album`, so it is correct now.